# PHP: str_replace from end of string

Tags: php

This is my string:

`Hello world Hello How are You Hello world`

I want to replace last `Hello world` to `HW`

> Result:

`Hello world Hello How are You HW`

`str_replace` replaces all `Hello world` but I want to replace from end (if exists)

Comment: Show us the code that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to use a single function for this, but it doesn't exist. You can build your own function, like this:

```
<?php

function str_replace_last3($search, $replace, $subject)
{
    $pos = strrpos($subject, $search);
    if ($pos === FALSE) return $subject;
    return substr($subject, 0, $pos) . $replace . 
           substr($subject, $pos + strlen($search));
}

echo str_replace_last3('Hello world', 
                       'HW', 
                       'Hello world Hello How are You Hello world');
```

This returns:

```
Hello world Hello How are You HW
```

See: [strrpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

Note that this function doesn't work with array arguments as the original `str_replace()` does.

Comment: How do you provide an answer like the above without checking what someone has tried so far? Second, have you checked your function with all the possible inputs? What if some inputs do not match?

Comment: If you read the question you see that Parsa has tried `str_replace()`. I agree that more effort could have been taken. That being said: It's my time to waste. You're right about the check for a non-matching subject. I'll change the code.

Comment: I think the parameters are in the wrong order:

```
    function str_replace_last($search, $replace, $subject)
    {
        $pos = strrpos($subject, $search);
        if ($pos === FALSE) return $subject;
        return substr($subject, 0, $pos) . $replace . substr($subject, $pos + strlen($search));
    }
```

Comment: @JohnS I agree. I will change the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can use `preg_replace()`

using the pattern `Hello world$`

```
<?php
$re = '/Hello world$/m';
$str = 'Hello world Hello How are You Hello world';

echo preg_replace($re, 'HW', $str);
?>
```

This would need the least code if do it in one line

```
preg_replace('/Hello world$/m','HW','Hello world Hello How are You Hello world');
```

Comment: I think I have to eat humble pie, clearly it is possible with one function. I do however think that the string given in the question is just an example. Can you guarantee that your solution will work for any set of input strings? Perhaps a reference to [preg_quote()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) is in order?